# PHP strtotime issue

Tags: strtotime

I'm inserting many dates into a database. Most of them write normally, so that I can use `strtotime` to get the time like '1299XXXXXX'.

However, some dates, are written like this: day/month/year hour/minute/seconds

```
echo strtotime('12/03/2011 18:00:52'); //this will get 132293165220
```

Thus, I can not insert all of the date in my database. How to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? Are you saying your users enter dates without complying with a format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$temp_date = strtotime('12/03/2011 18:00:52');
echo date('m/d/Y', $temp_date);
```

where 'm/d/Y' is format of your choose: if want full -> 'm/d/Y H:i:s',

if only date part -> 'm/d/Y'

more on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: right, use `strtotime(date('Y-d-m H:i:s',strtotime('12/03/2011 18:00:52')));//1299949252`

Answer (score 1):

I looked around and could not get anything comprehensive so i decided to write my own date converter. Well parameterized.

```
function convert_datetime($datestr,$separator,$mysqltouk) {
    if(!empty($datestr))
    {
      if($mysqltouk=='dmy')         
          {
        list($y,$m,$d ) = explode($separator, $datestr);
        $mk=mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
        $timestamp=strftime('%d-%m-%Y',$mk);
      }
      else if ($mysqltouk='ymd')
          {
            list($d, $m, $y) = explode($separator, $datestr);
        $mk=mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
        $timestamp=strftime('%Y-%m-%d',$mk);
          }
    }
      return $timestamp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the date using the `date` function:

```
date('h:i:s', strtotime('12/03/2011 18:00:52'));
```